# Only show what's new in a file

Tags: ubuntu, diff

I want to find out what was added to a log file between 2 tasks. Right now the way I do it is:

**content of test.log initially**

```
aaa
bbb
```

**saving content of the log**

```
$ cp test.log test.log.before
```

**doing something**

**content of test.log after doing something**

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

**saving content of the log**

```
$ cp test.log test.log.after
```

**showing the difference**

```
$ diff test.log.before test.log.after
2a3
> ccc
```

What I don't like with this method is that I get some noise from `diff` (`2a3` and `>`) whereas I just want `ccc`.

**Q: Is there a way I can just get the difference between the 2 log files (i.e. what is new in test.log.after, `ccc`)?**

I had a look at [diff's man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) but I don't see anything obvious there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the additions only you can filter the output such as:

```
$ diff test.log.before test.log.after | grep "^>" | cut -c 3-
```

However, you will lose the deletions if any.

Answer (score 4):

If you always do a before and after such that the end of the after file will contain the new content then you could use [comm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/comm.1.html).

```
$ cat before 
aaa
bbb

$ cat after
aaa
bbb
ccc

$ comm -3  after before
ccc
```

Comment: But, the files should be sorted!

Comment: This works as expected if the files are the same up to the point that new stuff is added.

Comment: `comm` is OK but output comes out tabulated. I prefer the `grep`+`cut` alternative.

Comment: that's why I did `after before` so that the output (which contains the changes) is at the beginning of the line, doing `before after` would give you tabs to deal with.